# Get nodes from XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq

I'm loading a XML file in which the elements are loaded in a combobox.

//Code:

```
 XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"E:\\New.xml");
     var query = (from xEle in xDoc.Descendants("Description")
        select new { value = xEle.Value, text = xEle.Attribute("Value").Value }).ToList();

 cmbLoad.ValueMember = "value";
 cmbLoad.DisplayMember = "text";
 cmbLoad.DataSource = query;
```

In the above code i took the values and loaded into a combobox. But now i have to get the values according to the node. Not sure where to change the query.

XML File which loads the values:

```
<MasterValues>
     <Gender>
        <Description Value="1">Name</Description>
     </Gender>
 </MasterValues>
```

My new XML file:

```
 <MasterValues>
     <Gender>
        <Description Value="1">Name</Description>
     </Gender>
     <Proof>
        <Description Value="1">License</Description>
     </Proof>
 </MasterValues>
```

How to include the node(Gender,Proof) inside the query which is to be checked and then get loaded?

Comment: It's not clear, you want to get the values and put the values to what?  a List<>? or you just want to get the value of an item of your combobox? Your query already gets the values for you.

Comment: I agree with King King - it's *really* unclear what you're trying to achieve here. What do you mean by "the node inside the query which is to be checked and then get loaded"?

Comment: I have to check with the Gender,Proof inside the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Elements` method:

```
xDoc.Root.Elements("MasterValues").Elements("Gender").Elements("Description");
```

Or, alternatively,you can use `XPathSelectElements`

```
xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/MasterValues/Gender/Description");
```

let me know for furthar help.